Thriller involving a woman and a man with a dog being attacked in Central Park
I watched this movie as a kid (approximately 2000-2010) with my dad.  I can't for the life of me find it anywhere...
What I Remember:

a woman, man, and dog are attacked in Central Park
The woman is the only one to survive
After the attack she suffers from Agoraphobia (essentially she's afraid to leave her apartment)
At some point she buys a gun


Could it be The Brave One with Jodie Foster?

@steelersquirrel's comment is right: the movie must be "The Brave One" (2007).
The plot goes like this:

As radio show host Erica Bain (Jodie Foster) and her fiancé David (Naveen Andrews) are walking their dog at night at Stranger's Gate in New York's Central Park, they are attacked by three violent criminals who film the whole attack on their phones. David dies from his injuries, and Erica, while seriously injured, survives. Angry and traumatized, she attempts to purchase a gun. Terrified and unwilling to wait the month required to obtain a gun legally, she buys a Kahr K9 semi-automatic pistol from a black market gun dealer.


ok thank you so so much! this is the movie!!!! I literally love you right now!
